# cannot load and read from properties file

Tags: gradle

My grade java project has the following structure.

As you can see the resources folder is in present in the class path.

But when I run the following in a class under java folder

```
new File("somefile.txt").exists()
```

I get `FileNotFoundException`.

Could anyone help me find why I am not able to access this file. 
This is in the class path.

[image]

Comment: May be you can give clean build a shot. Delete build folders  + invalidate intellij cache + gradle refresh (after deleting old artifact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String filePath= classLoader.getResource("filename").getFile();
new File(filePath).exists();
```

For more info, you can go through [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) tutorial.

Comment: classLoader.getResource("filename").getFile(); -- I got to this yesterday by reading the java docs but yeah accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your issue like below

```
Properties prop = new Properties();          
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("somefile.txt"); 
if (inputStream != null) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
} else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file '" + fileName + "' not found in the classpath");
}
```

I found it from the post [How to read properties file in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-io/how-to-read-properties-file-in-java.html)